# Gmail is ignoring my HTML emails

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

You've probably come across this error before. I cannot seem to fix it. 
Gmail seems to be ignoring my HTML emails and is just showing the code. 
All other clients (or all that I know of) are displaying the content correctly.

Here is my code (with certain things changed to hide the name)

```
     $to = "$EmailAddress";
     $subject = "My subject!";
     $headers = "From: no-reply@mydomain.co.uk\r\n" .
     "X-Mailer: php";
     $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
     $message = '<html><body>';
     $message .= '<center><img width="300px" src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/images/mylogo.png"/><br />';
     $message .= '<br /><br />';
     $message .= '<h2>Hello '.$UserName.',</h2>';
     $message .= '<b>Thanks for joining!</b><br /><br />';
     $message .= 'Please find your login details below.';
     $message .= '_____________________________________<br /><br />';
     $message .= 'Username: '.$UserName.'<br/>
                  Password: '.$Password.'<br />
                  <br />';
     $message .= '_____________________________________<br /><br />';
     $message .= 'Thanks,<br/>My company.<br/>';
     $message .= '<br/><a target="_new" href="http://www.mydomain.co.uk"/>www.mydomain.co.uk</a>';
     $message .= '</center>';
     $message .= 'my company &copy; 2012';
     $message .= '</html></body>';

     $success = mail($to,$subject,$headers,$message);
```

my Question is, is there a way to either offer an alternative plain text version of the email should the email client not be able to read this code or is there something I need to add in order for Gmail to understand it?

I apologise if this is a duplicate, but I cannot seem to find this question on here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use a class to build your HTML emails instead of doing all the stuff manually. This would especially have the advantage that you can easily add a plaintext version, too (html-only emails are **very** annoying!).

Comment: HTML-only emails are very easy to flag as "probably spam" (and my email service does that).

Comment: Try phpMailer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! I will try a Class and @Mikey I will look at that link. Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have some typo's in your code, i don't know how other client displaying content correctly. i worked on them and got succeeded, hope will work for u too, try this;

```
$to = "$EmailAddress";
$subject = "My subject!";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<center><img width="300px" src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/images/mylogo.png"/><br />';
$message .= '<br /><br />';
$message .= '<h2>Hello '.$UserName.',</h2>';
$message .= '<b>Thanks for joining!</b><br /><br />';
$message .= 'Please find your login details below.';
$message .= '_____________________________________<br /><br />';
$message .= 'Username: '.$UserName.'<br/>
Password: '.$Password.'<br />
<br />';
$message .= '_____________________________________<br /><br />';
$message .= 'Thanks,<br/>My company.<br/>';
$message .= '<br/><a target="_new" href="http://www.mydomain.co.uk"/>www.mydomain.co.uk</a>';
$message .= '</center>';
$message .= 'my company &copy; 2012';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$success = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

[image]
This is what u looking for

Comment: Not sure, but it seems but when dealing with gmail as recipient, we cannot change headers without affecting mail delivery. I had to comment `$mail->ClearCustomHeaders();` and all custom headers`$mail->AddCustomHeader();` and now gmail is receiving emails just fine

Comment: It is almost impossible to send emails with HTML

Answer (score -1):

I don't think what you are trying here is standard. Emails are written in plain/text usually, not text/html. Theres a option to send emails as a mime-multipart message, but then you have a text/plain version for browsers withouth text/html support.  You should be using a class to shield yourself from implementation details of mime.

Mi comment is for advanced PHP users.  Begginers can do things manually, they don't have the experience of what things will break doing it that way. So the top voted comment here is enough for begginers. Professionales are better served using a class that create a correct mime type multipart file.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

Content-type: html;

I Have used it to solve a problem in my application.