# Mail not receiving using PHP

Tags: php, email

This is my mailing code:

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$user_subject = "Ticket - Budget Notification";
$user_headers = "From: mariyadavis90@gmail.com\r\n";
$user_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$user_headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$user_part = '<html><body>';
$user_part .= '<div style="background-color: #EEEEEE;border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;padding: 10px 10px 20px;width: 500px; float:left;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">';
$user_part1 = '<div style="width:500px;">';
$user_part1 .= '<div style="width:500px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">';
$user_part1 .= '<div style="float:left;width:150px;color:#666666;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">';
$user_part1 .= '</div></div>';
$user_part1 .= '<div style="width:450px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc; height:auto; float:left;font-size:12px;margin-left:50px; font-weight:bold;">';
$user_part3 = '</div></div></div>';
$user_part3 .= '</body></html>';
$user_center_part1 = '';    
$user_center_part = 'The following Tickets are reached its budget ,';   
$user_center_part2='<div style="float:left;width:auto;color:#000000;font-size:12px;margin-left:75px; font-weight:bold; height:auto; margin-top:10px;">Ticket #10 reached 100% of its budget</div>';
$user_to = 'galtech.staffs@gmail.com';
if($user_to){

        $user_center_part1 = 'Dear Admin ,';
        $user_message = $user_part.$user_center_part1.$user_part1.$user_center_part.$user_center_part2.$user_part3; 
        if(mail($user_to, $user_subject, $user_message, $user_headers))
        {
            echo "Mail Send Successfully";
        }else{
            echo "Mail Not Send Successfully";
        }
    }
?>
```

When I using this mailing code I can't get any mail in my account. What is the problem in my code? Nothing will be received in the account. It displays `Mail Sent Successfully` every time.

Comment: Your mail server log says...?

Comment: What does `mail()` return? Have you checked your spam and junk folders in your email?

Comment: mail() not returing any errors,I checked the spam no mail recieved there

Comment: I assume you are replacing "test@gmail.com" for your own email address. If that's correct, check you have error reporting enabled or check your server logs for errors.

Comment: i edited the code ,check it,But it still never return any errors

Answer (score 1):

Your `From:` header looks wonky and most mail servers will happily reject your email for coming with an invalid header like that. Please make sure that it contains an actual email address and try again.

Comment: It needs to be a valid email address, like `test@example.com`, not a URL.

Comment: @arxanas Ok i changed it again as `$user_headers = "From: mariyadavis90@gmail.com\r\n";` but nothing will happen

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your grammar. You say nothing will happen. Have you tried it? (Also, you don't need to put an email address that can actually receive mail — it just has to be in the form of a valid email address.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9843/discussion-between-kichu-user-and-arxanas)

Answer (score 0):

i notice that your receiving email is gmail, that is; 'galtech.staffs@gmail.com' 
i used your script for testing purpose and i am getting mails, but as a spam. i am sure your are receiving them too, php mail function creates issues using gmail as a receiver email, any way after editing header section i am getting mail in my inbox, here are the results;

[image: this is what you looking for]

**Try this;**

```
$user_subject = "Ticket - Budget Notification";
$user_headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$user_part = '<html><body>';
$user_part .= '<div style="background-color: #EEEEEE;border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;padding: 10px 10px 20px;width: 500px; float:left;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">';
$user_part1 = '<div style="width:500px;">';
$user_part1 .= '<div style="width:500px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc;">';
$user_part1 .= '<div style="float:left;width:150px;color:#666666;margin-left:20px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">';
$user_part1 .= '</div></div>';
$user_part1 .= '<div style="width:450px;background-color:#eeeeee;padding: 10px 0 20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dcdcdc; height:auto; float:left;font-size:12px;margin-left:50px; font-weight:bold;">';
$user_part3 = '</div></div></div>';
$user_part3 .= '</body></html>';
$user_center_part1 = '';    
$user_center_part = 'The following Tickets are reached its budget ,';   
$user_center_part2='<div style="float:left;width:auto;color:#000000;font-size:12px;margin-left:75px; font-weight:bold; height:auto; margin-top:10px;">Ticket #10 reached 100% of its budget</div>';

$user_to = 'youremailid@gmail.com';

       $user_center_part1 = 'Dear Admin ,';
       $user_message = $user_part.$user_center_part1.$user_part1.$user_center_part.$user_center_part2.$user_part3; 
        if(mail($user_to, $user_subject, $user_message, $user_headers))

            echo "Mail Send Successfully";
        else
            echo "Mail Not Send Successfully";
```

Comment: you can also consider one of my previous answers regarding this issue here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908791/gmail-is-ignoring-my-html-emails/9911066#9911066

Comment: are you sure you using header only like this; $user_headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

Comment: then contact with your web-host for this specific issue, as you can see (in image) webbox is my web-host and no issues on my side, good luck.